# Cant understand why I'm getting this warning

Tags: c, function, pointers, variables, printf

```
double S = 0;
    double *pSum = &S;

    double P = 0;
    double *pAverage = &P;

    printf("The average and sum of the variables: %lf %lf", &S, &P);
```

I'm working with pointers and functions but for some reason I can't understand why I'm getting 2 warning specifically

non-float passed as argument `3` when float is required in call to `printf` actual type: `double *`.
non-float passed as argument `2` when float is required in call to `printf` actual type: `double *`.

To be completely honest I don't know what to try to get rid of the warning.

Comment: You are passing pointers to `printf()`. Do you want to view the pointer values? In that case format with %p. If not, remove the address operators.

Comment: You have done some things **very** correctly: 1) Enabled many compiler warnings.  2) posted the exact error message.

Comment: Basically: printf wants parameters passed by value, scanf wants parameters passed by reference. This is because scanf needs to write data into the parameters and thereby return those values to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have mixed arguments for `scanf` (where you need to pass pointers to the variables) and `printf` (which want values, not pointers).

The correct solution is to not use the pointer-to operator `&`:

```
printf("The average and sum of the variables: %lf %lf", S, P);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`printf("The average and sum of the variables: %lf %lf", S, P);`

to get the values from the varriables directly or to use:

`printf("The average and sum of the variables: %lf %lf", *pSum, *pAverage);`

to get the value from the pointers= `*` before a pointer means "Give me the value of that pointer"